# How were the rest of the Joestars (minus Holly) able to retain their stands after the events of Stardust Crusaders?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Jotaro, Joseph, and the rest of the group in Part 3 traveled to Egypt to defeat DIO because Holly's stand was killing her, and by killing DIO, the stand would disappear as well.

However, the rest of the Joestars are able to retain their stands(Jotaro and Joseph wielded Star Platinum and Hermit Purple respectively in Diamond is Unbreakable). Furthermore, Josuke and Giorno were shown to be suffering from the same illness Holly was inflicted with when manifesting her stand, but both of them were able to fully manifest and mature their stands.

So, why's Holly the odd one out? Did DIO specifically target Holly to goad the Joestars into trying to defeat him? Or does she actually have a stand, but it hasn't been mentioned in the canon?

Comment: I am quite sure that you can answer the question in the title if you watch all Jojo episode which I assume you did since you mention Diamond is Unbreakable. Is just how Stand work.

Comment: For other question It clearly stated in chapter 121 or anime ep3. `Her gentle, non-violent soul made her lack the mental strength necessary to control the Stand, slowly making her ill with a harmful high fever and nearly ending her life`.

Comment: @someoneuseless There are stand users with no violent tendencies or fighting spirits that were still able to retain their stands. Shizuka Joestar has Achtung Baby despite being a literal baby, and I think in Golden Heart, Golden Ring, the stand user of The Cure really didn't have much of a fighting spirit.